# Referencing records from the same table multiple times in a join query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I decided to store information about a game I'm making in several tables, but I ran into a problem: each item in my game can have up to three abilities, which there are few constraints on. This leads to a problem when trying to join tables and display the ability name.

I am using MySQL server and I created a view which combines all the information for items into one huge *table*. The problem is that if an item has three different abilities, it does not meet the where condition of the view.

Here are the table definitions with significance to this problem (there are more tables than this):

```
CREATE TABLE items_misc (
Item_ID INT(4) NOT NULL,
Item_Hash INT(4) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Ability_One INT(4),
Ability_Two INT(4),
Ability_Three INT(4),
element_id INT(2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(Item_ID),
INDEX(Item_Hash),
FOREIGN KEY(Item_ID) REFERENCES items_names(IID),
FOREIGN KEY(Ability_One) REFERENCES item_abilities(AID),
FOREIGN KEY(Ability_Two) REFERENCES item_abilities(AID),
FOREIGN KEY(Ability_Three) REFERENCES item_abilities(AID),
FOREIGN KEY(element_id) REFERENCES element_types(EID)
);

CREATE TABLE item_abilities(
AID INT(4) NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Description VARCHAR(99) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(AID)
);
```

Then here's the WHERE clause of my CREATE VIEW statement:

```
WHERE items_names.IID = items_stats.Item_ID AND
items_names.IID = items_misc.Item_ID AND
item_types.TID = items_stats.type_id AND
element_types.EID = items_misc.element_id AND
item_abilities.AID = items_misc.Ability_One AND
item_abilities.AID = items_misc.Ability_Two AND
item_abilities.AID = items_misc.Ability_Three;
```

How do I change the join condition or the tables to account for the fact that each item could have three different abilities coming from the same pool of abilities (i.e, ability order does not matter)?

Comment: Would an OR statement suffice?
      (item_abilities.AID = items_misc.Ability_One OR
      item_abilities.AID = items_misc.Ability_Two OR
      item_abilities.AID = items_misc.Ability_Three)

Comment: Elaborate please; the WHERE clause is the join condition

Comment: Would that still join them, also, how would I show the ability's name under this structure if the abilities are different ?

Comment: I'd be interested in the full query of that view. I suppose that you perform a  cartesian product of the tables, which is not so effective, instead of using join. probably you need to join `item_abilities` 3 times on each `ability_<number>`, instead of just once.

Comment: As @lp_ pointed out, you need to join the ITEM_ABILITY three times with an alias for each.

Comment: @lp_ I assure you it isnt the cartesian product... just accidently ran it on the entire table set though… Though I did not make aliases in the FROM clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get values for from `item_abilities` for each of the three abilities, then you'll need to reference `item_abilities` three times in the `from` clause:

```
FROM items_names,
     items_stats,
     items_misc,
     item_types,
     element_types,
     item_abilities item_abilities1,
     item_abilities item_abilities2,
     item_abilities item_abilities3
WHERE items_names.IID = items_stats.Item_ID AND
items_names.IID = items_misc.Item_ID AND
item_types.TID = items_stats.type_id AND
element_types.EID = items_misc.element_id AND
item_abilities1.AID = items_misc.Ability_One AND
item_abilities2.AID = items_misc.Ability_Two AND
item_abilities3.AID = items_misc.Ability_Three;
```

Incidentally, it is highly recommend that you use SQL-1999 joins rather than joining in the `where` clause:

```
FROM items_names
     JOIN items_stats ON items_names.IID = items_stats.Item_ID
     JOIN items_misc ON items_names.IID = items_misc.Item_ID
     JOIN item_types ON item_types.TID = items_stats.type_id
     JOIN element_types ON element_types.EID = items_misc.element_id
     JOIN item_abilities item_abilities1
          ON item_abilities1.AID = items_misc.Ability_One
     JOIN item_abilities item_abilities2
          ON item_abilities2.AID = items_misc.Ability_Two
     JOIN item_abilities item_abilities3
          ON item_abilities3.AID = items_misc.Ability_Three;
```

Comment: Well, once my thing stops showing the Cartesian product, I'll give this one a try; looks promising!

Comment: In the select clause, I reference the aliased versions?

Comment: Yes, that way you can reference fields related to each of the ability fields.

Comment: I was never taught that join format, I was taught the join condition way. Doesnt make a different in my system.  I learned SQL from a book to begin with.